# How tight does a piston need to be to retain water at 80 PSI and room temperature?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, estimation

This question involves computing the minimal space that water will leak through.

For example, if we have a piston and cylinder and the water in the cylinder is at 80 PSI, what is the maximum clearance between the piston and the wall of the cylinder such that no water will leak out? Is there an equation for this?

Comment: This is really an engineering question. Some water will always leak past. The problem is to reduce the leakage to an acceptable level, and there are various engineering tricks to solve this, depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

From the standpoint of physics, a leakproof piston seal would have to possess a clearance of less than one water molecule's diameter. In practical terms this is an unattainable goal, since if the piston and cylinder were that close together it is guaranteed that they would be touching somewhere over their mutual contact area, and would therefore stick.

For low pressures (less than 10 PSI) it is possible to make a *nearly* leakproof piston-to-cylinder seal using a precision-drawn glass tube fitted with a precision-ground glass piston, in which the piston-to-cylinder clearance is so small (less than 25 microns) that the capillary forces acting on the liquid/air interface, coupled with the viscosity of the water, are fully dominant within that gap- and working the piston back and forth causes no liquid leakage out the gap or air intrusion into the cylinder. In effect, the liquid itself establishes its own seal. This design is called a *precision ground-glass syringe* and is commonly used to dispense liquids which would attack the elastomers that are commonly used for tip seals.

However, evaporation out the gap will still allow water to escape.

As an aside, note that the pressurized *gas cylinders* used to help lift hoods and trunk lids on cars, which contain rubber seals for a leakproof piston-to-cylinder seal, last thousands of extension and contraction cycles and retain their original internal pressure for decades.

Comment: I find this hard to believe. There are high pressure piston based water pumps and I do not believe they leak. I think there is an equation that tells the clearance necessary for this, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: I find this hard to believe. There are high pressure piston based water pumps and I do not believe they leak. I think there is an equation that tells the clearance necessary for this, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: the reason they do not leak is that they all contain elastomeric seals.

Comment: that is because they all contain elastomeric seals. I know of no such equation.